# In my redux store array, I have an undefined item at 0 index. I am not sure how it is there?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm learning redux. This is a simple project for understanding react redux. The basic idea is to have two components at the same level, in component1 we add the items, keep it in store and in component2 we display the items from the store.

**Code for component 1**

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import store from "../store/index";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

const Component1 = (props) => {
    let [inputTab, handleInputTab] = useState("");
    return ( <div>
        <input onChange={(e)=>{
            handleInputTab(e.target.value);
            
        }}
            value={inputTab}
        />
        <button onClick={()=>{
            props.addItem({inputTab});
            console.log(store.getState());
            handleInputTab("")
        }}>Add</button>
    </div> );
}
 
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
      // dispatching plain actions
      addItem: (listItem) => dispatch({ type: 'ADD_ITEM', payload: listItem }),
      
    }
  }
export default connect(null,mapDispatchToProps)(Component1);
```

**Code for component 2**

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from "react-redux";

const Component2 = (props) => {
    if(props.length <= 1){
        return <div>tetst</div>
    }
    return ( <div>
    
    {props.list.map((item, index) => (
       
       item != undefined  && <p key={index}>{item.inputTab}</p>
        
    ))}
    </div> 
    );
}
 
const mapStateToProps = state =>{
   
    return {
        list: state.list
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Component2);
```

**Action**

```
const ADD_ITEM = "ADD_ITEM";

export function addItem(payload) {
  return {
    type: ADD_ITEM,
    payload
  };
}
```

**Reducer**

```
const initialState = {
    list:[]
}

function addItemReducer(state = initialState, action){
    if(action.type="ADD_ITEM"){
        return {
           
        list: [...state.list, action.payload]
        }
    }
    return state;
}

export default addItemReducer
```

**Store**

```
import { createStore } from "redux";
import addItemReducer from "../reducers/index"

export default createStore(addItemReducer,);
```

**Problem**
On console logging the state, I notice an undefined item at 0 index of the list array. I am not sure where it is coming from.

```
{list: Array(3)}
list: Array(3)
0: undefined
1: {inputTab: "a"}
2: {inputTab: "b"}
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: Can you please share the code in a plnkr, or sandbox or any cloud code. In order to run and test where is the issue. 

It seems like when the addItem action is dispatched its adding an undefined first element in the array. 

Please share the code so I can help you

Comment: in your `Reducer` you have `action.type="ADD_ITEM"` which will always resolve to true, you should type `action.type == "ADD_ITEM"`

Comment: Can't believe I missed that. That was it, thanks a lot @LouayAlosh .Also, It should be "===" and not "==" right?

Comment: Good eyes @LouayAlosh, jajajaj I was writing its jjajaa.
I'm happy its solved, good for you vade

Comment: double equals `==` is enough here, and sometimes it can solve what cannot three equals `===` do because it prevent coercion

Comment: no @clenondavis, please read more about `==` vs `===` at https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/1st-ed/types%20%26%20grammar/ch4.md#loose-equals-vs-strict-equals

Comment: @vade at least give your vote to Louay Alosh comment, lol

Comment: @LouayAlosh, I agree with you about the useless of `===` in this context. But I get kind of curiouse about your "No... please..." In which part you not agree in my comments, so i can understand you

Comment: @clenondavis I do not have the required reputation to vote on comments.

Comment: @vade no problem, i did it for you. 
I'm happy you solve your issue.